# How to organize git repository for android and server code

Tags: android, git, networking

I would like to develop an Android application that will communicate with a node js server. I think there may be some models I want to share among 2 applications, I would like to put it in the same repository so that I don't have duplicate code. How could I organize my Git repo to achieve this? I guess it would be some thing similar how modules in intellij project, but I'm not sure. Thank you very much
I am also open to suggestion for other ways of implementing network service (i.e cloud,...) if you have any.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to put it in the same repository so that I don't have duplicate code. How could I organize my Git repo to achieve this?

One option is to:

- isolate those models in their own git repo
- reference that unique repo twice, that is one in each Git repos per application, **[as a submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)**.